# Why doesn't my prime factorization of all integers up to n work?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, primes, prime-factoring

I'm a beginner in C#.

I tried to create a program that calculates the prime factorization of `n`. And it worked. Here it is:

```
Console.WriteLine("Write a number.");

        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        bool[] p = new bool[(int)Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt(n))+2];

        for(int i=2; i<p.Length; i++)
        {
            p[i]=true;
        }

        for(int i=2; i<=Math.Sqrt(p.Length); i++)
        {
            if(p[i])
            {
                for(int j=i*i; j<p.Length; j+=i)
                {
                    p[j]=false;
                }
            }
        }

        int[] P = new int[p.Length];

        int k=0;

        for(int i=2; i<p.Length; i++)
        {
            if(p[i])
            {
                P[k]=i;
                k++;
            }
        }

        Array.Resize(ref P, k);

        int N=n;

        for(int i=0; i<P.Length; i++)
        {
            if(n%P[i]==0)
            {
                int j=1;

                while(n%Math.Pow(P[i],j+1)==0)
                {
                    j++;
                }

                if(n!=N)
                {
                    Console.Write(" . ");
                }

                Console.Write(""+P[i]+"^"+j);
                n/=(int)Math.Pow(P[i],j);
            }
        }

        if(n!=1 && n!=N)
        {
            Console.Write(" . "+n+"^1");
        }

        if(n==N)
        {
            Console.Write(""+n+"^1");
        }

        Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Then I tried to make a program that calculates the prime factorization of *all* integers up to `n`. But it doesn't work. Here it is:

```
Console.WriteLine("Write a number.");

        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        bool[] p = new bool[(int)Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt(n))+2];

        for(int i=2; i<p.Length; i++)
        {
            p[i]=true;
        }

        for(int i=2; i<=Math.Sqrt(p.Length); i++)
        {
            if(p[i])
            {
                for(int j=i*i; j<p.Length; j+=i)
                {
                    p[j]=false;
                }
            }
        }

        int[] P = new int[p.Length];

        int k=0;

        for(int i=2; i<p.Length; i++)
        {
            if(p[i])
            {
                P[k]=i;
                k++;
            }
        }

        Array.Resize(ref P, k);

        for(int m=2; m<=n; m++)
        {
            int M=m;

            for(int i=0; i<P.Length; i++)
            {
                if(m%P[i]==0)
                {
                    int j=1;

                    while(m%Math.Pow(P[i],j+1)==0)
                    {
                        j++;
                    }

                    if(m!=M)
                    {
                        Console.Write(" . ");
                    }

                    Console.Write(""+P[i]+"^"+j);
                    m/=(int)Math.Pow(P[i],j);
                }
            }

            if(m!=1 && m!=M)
            {
                Console.Write(" . "+m+"^1");
            }

            if(m==M)
            {
                Console.Write(""+m+"^1");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("");
        }

        Console.ReadKey(true);
```

When I run the program it just displays:

> 2^1
>   2^1
>   2^1
>   2^1
>   ...

What errors did I make? It's strange because I just used the first program to make the second one, so there was no reason for the second program not to work...

Comment: And the second lesson is Name Your Variables. P's, J's, i's, m's are hard to understand.

Comment: And the third lesson is to put code into methods. If your first program had already had a method taking as input `N`, then the second program is simply a `for` loop that calls the first program's method. It couldn't _not_ work, as long as the first program worked. (Okay, I overstate a bit...no programming language is completely fool-proof...but it would be _WAY_ harder for even a novice programmer to break it).

Comment: @BillGregg "hard to understand" - without comments (documentation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a different approach to your problem.

```
Console.WriteLine(FormatFactors(120));
Console.WriteLine(FormatFactors(7200));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
2^3 * 3 * 5
2^5 * 3^2 * 5^2
```

---

```
string FormatFactors(int n)
{
    return String.Join(" * ", 
              Factors(n).GroupBy(x => x)
                        .Select(g => g.Key + (g.Count() > 1 ? "^" + g.Count() : ""))
            );
}

IEnumerable<int> Factors(int n)
{
    int i=2;
    while(i<=n)
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
        {
            yield return i;
            n /= i;
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @jmorc Maybe this green tick on the left and 3 upvotes mean something to you.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

The problem was that the value of the variable `m` changed inside the for loop...

So I just modified this:

```
 for(int m=2; m<=n; m++)
    {
        int M=m;
```

into this:

```
for(int q=2; q<=n; q++)
        {
            int m=q;

            int M=q;
```

And yes, I know, I really need to learn how to use the debugger...

Comment: Indeed but most of us forgot the days they had to run to the their books to find out what it told them :) Honestly. reading your code I could not find the fault without my debugger. I would suggest use more readable/significant variable Names and Comments. you'll not regret that :)